# arrayadapter for spinner not working in fragment, requires resource id

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

i am getting an error that ArrayAdapter does not have resource id, however the resource id is used here and i used similar code in an activity with no problem however this is in a fragment.  is there something i am supposed to do differently because it is in a fragment?  and that is why it is not working?

i made a xml layout and put a textView in it as required.

any ideas on how to get this working?

stack trace

```
 07-16 20:11:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(14278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-16 20:11:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(14278): java.lang.IllegalStateException:   ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
 07-16 20:11:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(14278):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
 07-16 20:11:44.290: E/AndroidRuntime(14278):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
```

oncreateview method from the fragment. this method is where all the action is

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.small_tank_layout11, container, false);

        activity = getActivity();

         // set shared preferences variable with shared preferences object for use
        prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("smallTankPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        textViewOne = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textViewTwo = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        spinnerOne = (Spinner) result.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        buttonOne = (Button) result.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // get stored title quesion and set text
        smallTank11question = prefs.getString("smallTank11question", "");
        textViewOne.setText(smallTank11question);

        // get arraylist from json string
        Gson gson = new Gson();
         Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
         smallTank11WeatherNames = prefs.getString("smallTank11WeatherNames", "");
         smallTank11WeatherNamesArray = gson.fromJson(smallTank11WeatherNames, type);

         // get the weather selected indicator stored in shared prefereces
         smallTank11WeatherSelected = prefs.getInt("smallTank11WeatherSelected", -1);

    //put strings of weather selections into spinner
       ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.small_tank_spinnerlayout_one, smallTank11WeatherNamesArray);  // layout for spinner itself
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.small_tank_spinnerlayout_one); // layout for spinner dropdown items
        spinnerOne.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        return result;

    } // end oncreateview
```

Edit here i added the code for small_tank_spinnerlayout_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to use a custom layout in your array adapter you need to make a 'Custom' array adapter, not the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to why the arrayAdapter was not working.

first the ArrayAdapter code itself is correct and no changes were needed

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.small_tank_spinnerlayout_one, smallTank11WeatherNamesArray);  // layout for spinner itself
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.small_tank_spinnerlayout_one); // layout for spinner dropdown items
    spinnerOne.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

the problem was in the xml file used to populate the views in the spinner, small_tank_spinnerlayout_one.xml,  in this file there was a textView enclosed inside of a linearLayout as you can see if you look above in the question where I posted the code for the xml file.  this is what caused the errors.

I changed the code by removing the linearLayout from the xml file so the only code in the file is for the textView as shown below and it works now.

lesson learned, for this version of ArrayAdapter that I am using, you cannot enclose the textView in any kind of layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:padding="20dp"
     android:textSize="14pt"     
     android:gravity="center"
 />
```

in addition you don't have to name the textView, as I removed this line shown below and it still works

```
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.small_tank_spinnerlayout_one, smallTank11WeatherNamesArray);
```

you should point to which `TextView` to use from your layout.For that you should create your `ArrayAdapter` like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.small_tank_spinnerlayout_one, R.id.textView1, smallTank11WeatherNamesArray);
```

Where you are pointing first the layout to use for your `Spinner`'s items and the id of your `TextView` from that layout.If you are using

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.small_tank_spinnerlayout_one, smallTank11WeatherNamesArray);
```

your layout should have `TextView` with id : `android:id/textView1`

Comment: i tried that but now i am getting resource not found exception

Comment: there is probably a different way that you access resources in a fragment than a activity?   and another strange thing is that i did use the vary similar code earlier in an activity where the R.layout was used in place of the R.id.textView.  is is probably wrong but it did work.

Comment: Basically you want to create custom adapter for a spinner in Fragment?

Comment: yes. and i did look at the docs and it says that one of the versions of the method takes the resounce id, and i don't need to add the actual R.id of the textView.   i am looking through the code to see why it worked with the other activity and not with this fragment

Comment: Can you post the code of your : `small_tank_spinnerlayout_one` ?

Comment: yes i will post that code,  additionally i am finding that when i use R.id.textView1  it give resource not found exception and when i use R.layout it gives the error where resource needed is a textView